# How do I setup configuration when I use command line to build C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, exception

When my program tries to access the dll in the network drive, I got this error message.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///Z:\smcho\works\tasks\2011\ni\ng_fpgabackend\myclass.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load maybe dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch.
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
```

Following the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(VS.100).aspx), I got this info I need to have this configuration.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

How do I put this configuration info to what?
I use Visual Studio 2010, but I don't use Visual Studio IDE, but just have one simple batch file to build the C# code.

### ADDED

I found [this site](http://generally.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/using-appconfig-for-user-defined-runtime-parameters/) using App.config, and I think it may not be possible to use method with command line build.

Comment: +1 For building from the command line.

Comment: You'll want it in a app.config file

Comment: You build with msbuild, or use csc directly? (or something else maybe?). And what throws this exception? The compiler or your application.

Comment: @ppiotrowicz : I use csc directly, and the exception happens with application running. There is no problem with the compilations.

Comment: Please check out my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your output file is foo.exe. Create foo.exe.config, copy it right next to foo.exe and put this in it:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx)?

Comment: I added the attribute to the class in the dll that the main program calls, but I got the same error message.